# Terminating a thread in C++ from another thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, primes

Basically I'm finding primes with two threads. I split the range of possible primes in half for each thread or otherwise statically distribute the range between the threads. However the thread that has to deal with the smaller numbers will inevitably finish before the one that computes the larger ones. What I want to do is as soon as either thread goes trough it's range, terminate both threads and then give half of the rest of the range of the thread that hadn't finished to the one that did so that they would recursively even out and will always run in parallel. 
Ex: A(1-100) and B(100-200), A finishes first while B is still on 150. Both stop, A starts like A(150-175) and B like B(175-200).

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <queue>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
priority_queue<int> primes;
CRITICAL_SECTION critical;
struct args
{
    int begin;
    int end;
}par1, par2;

int e_prosto(int n)
{
    for(int i = 2; i*i<(n + 1) ; i++)
    if (n & 1 == 0 || n % i == 0) return 0;
    return 1;
}

unsigned int __stdcall rabotnik(void* n)
{
    struct args *lPar = (args*) n;
    for(int i = lPar->begin; i < lPar->end; i++)
    {
        if(e_prosto(i)){
            EnterCriticalSection(&critical);
            primes.push(i);
            LeaveCriticalSection(&critical);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int foo;
    printf(" Tarsene na prosti do: ");
    scanf("%d", &foo);
    par1.begin=1;
    par1.end=foo/2+1;
    par2.begin=foo/2+1;
    par2.end=foo;

    HANDLE hvadkaA, hvadkaB;
    InitializeCriticalSection(&critical);
    SYSTEMTIME st, now, then;

    hvadkaA = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &rabotnik, (void*)&par1, 0, 0);
    hvadkaB = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &rabotnik, (void*)&par2, 0, 0);
    ::GetSystemTime(&then);
    WaitForSingleObject(hvadkaA, INFINITE);
    WaitForSingleObject(hvadkaB, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(hvadkaA);
    CloseHandle(hvadkaB);

    ::GetSystemTime(&now);
    while(!primes.empty())
    {
        printf("%d \t", primes.top());
        primes.pop();
    }
    printf("\nGotov za %d milisec", abs(now.wMilliseconds - then.wMilliseconds));
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it would make more sense to set up a job queue for each thread.. killing/terminating short living threads, especially for prime finding sounds like a really bad idea..  do you do this solely as an  exercise for threading?

Comment: yes, i just looked into threads today, this is an exercise

Comment: Running a sieve multi-threaded seems like it would be a more interesting exercise.

Comment: a friend suggested using the sieve for prime finding but we couldn't figure out how to use it with both threads sharing the variable and not constantly needing locks and unlocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest rather then giving each thread one block A(1-100) and B(101-200) that each thread be assigned a modulo.  For example A would take all odd indexes, B would take all even indexes resulting in A {1,3,5,7,9,...,191,193,195,197,199} and B {2,4,6,8,...,190,192,194,196,198,200}.  This would probably be the quickest and easiest way to load balance the threads, since the complexity of the calculations would be evenly distributed.

The next suggestion would be to add a bool which indicates if it is ok to keep processing.  Then, before the start of each calculation you check if it is ok to proceed.  This way you can stop the calculation without terminating the thread, at the cost of one extra comparison each loop.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <queue>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool run;
priority_queue<int> primes;
CRITICAL_SECTION critical;
struct args
{
    int begin;
    int end;
}par1, par2;

int e_prosto(int n)
{
    for(int i = 2; i*i<(n + 1) ; i++)
    if (n & 1 == 0 || n % i == 0) return 0;
    return 1;
}

unsigned int __stdcall rabotnik(void* n)
{
    struct args *lPar = (args*) n;
    for(int i = lPar->begin; i < lPar->end && run; i++)
    {
        if(e_prosto(i)){
            EnterCriticalSection(&critical);
            primes.push(i);
            LeaveCriticalSection(&critical);
        }
    }
    run = false;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int foo;
    printf(" Tarsene na prosti do: ");
    scanf("%d", &foo);
    par1.begin=1;
    par1.end=foo/2+1;
    par2.begin=foo/2+1;
    par2.end=foo;
    run = true;

    HANDLE hvadkaA, hvadkaB;
    InitializeCriticalSection(&critical);
    SYSTEMTIME st, now, then;

    hvadkaA = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &rabotnik, (void*)&par1, 0, 0);
    hvadkaB = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &rabotnik, (void*)&par2, 0, 0);
    ::GetSystemTime(&then);
    WaitForSingleObject(hvadkaA, INFINITE);
    WaitForSingleObject(hvadkaB, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(hvadkaA);
    CloseHandle(hvadkaB);

    ::GetSystemTime(&now);
    while(!primes.empty())
    {
        printf("%d \t", primes.top());
        primes.pop();
    }
    printf("\nGotov za %d milisec", abs(now.wMilliseconds - then.wMilliseconds));
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

The other way would be to partition your range into many blocks, then when a thread completes give it a new block to process.  This has the advantage of not adding additional overhead to the calculation, but does require a bit more code (so you are reusing the threads and listening for any thread to complete, not just one).  To be of any value then you will probably need a larger range and you may need to vary block size by complexity (block sizes {1-100}, {101-150}, {151-175}, {176-183}, {184-187}, ...).  A quick example using your code (with symmetric block sizes):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <queue>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
priority_queue<int> primes;
CRITICAL_SECTION critical;
typedef struct args
{
    int begin;
    int end;

    //Helper method for initalizing struct
    void setAll(int inBegin, bool inEnd)
    {
    }

} *PArgs;

int e_prosto(int n)
{
    for(int i = 2; i*i<(n + 1) ; i++)
    if (n & 1 == 0 || n % i == 0) return 0;
    return 1;
}

static DWORD WINAPI rabotnik(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    struct args *lPar = (args*) lpParam;
    for(int i = lPar->begin; i < lPar->end; i++)
    {
        if(e_prosto(i)){
            EnterCriticalSection(&critical);
            primes.push(i);
            LeaveCriticalSection(&critical);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    const int NUM_THREAD = 2;           //Use named constant incase you want to change later.
    DWORD returnedThreadID;
    DWORD threadID[NUM_THREAD];
    HANDLE threadHandle[NUM_THREAD];    //Holds the handels for the threads.
    int foo,                            //Range size.
        fooBlockSize,                   //Number of elements in a block.
        nextBlock;
    PArgs par[NUM_THREAD];

    printf(" Tarsene na prosti do: ");
    scanf("%d", &foo);                  //Get range size from user.
    fooBlockSize = foo / (NUM_THREAD * 10); //Set number of elements in a block.

    InitializeCriticalSection(&critical);
    SYSTEMTIME st, now, then;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREAD; i++) 
    {
        par[i] = (PArgs) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(PArgs)); 
           // If the allocation fails, the system is out of memory so terminate execution.
        if( par[i] == NULL ){ cout<<"par HeapAlloc failed with error# "<<GetLastError()<<endl<<"Will now quit."<<endl; ExitProcess(2);}
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREAD; i++)
    {
        par[i]->begin = (fooBlockSize * i) + 1;
        par[i]->end = par[i]->begin + fooBlockSize;
        threadHandle[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, rabotnik, par[i], CREATE_SUSPENDED, &threadID[i]);
    }
    nextBlock = NUM_THREAD;

    ::GetSystemTime(&then);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREAD; i++)
    {
        ResumeThread(threadHandle[i]);      //Start threads
    }

    while( ((fooBlockSize * nextBlock) + 1) < foo)
    {
        returnedThreadID = WaitForMultipleObjects(NUM_THREAD, threadHandle, false, INFINITE);   //Wait for a thread to complete.
        for(int i = 0; i<NUM_THREAD;i++)
        {
            if(returnedThreadID = threadID[i])
            {
                //Update the thread's arguments with the new block.
                par[i]->begin = (fooBlockSize * nextBlock) + 1;
                par[i]->end = par[i]->begin + fooBlockSize;

                //Restart the thread.
                ResumeThread(threadHandle[i]);
                nextBlock++;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREAD; i++)
    {
        //Return heap memorry (good practice, though Windows should return it all when the process terminates).
        if (HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, par[i]) == 0)
        {
            cout<<"HeapFree failed for par["<<i<<"]"<<endl;
        }

        //Not sure we need to close the threads, but it was in original version.
        CloseHandle(threadHandle[i]);
    }

    ::GetSystemTime(&now);
    while(!primes.empty())
    {
        printf("%d \t", primes.top());
        primes.pop();
    }
    printf("\nGotov za %d milisec", abs(now.wMilliseconds - then.wMilliseconds));
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

There is a trade off between increasing the number of blocks vs block size.  In creasing the number of blocks means that there will be less time spent with only one block able to process (thread[0] completes and there is nothing left to process while thread[1] is finishing up), but also means the there will me more time spent waiting for the dispatcher loop to assign a new block to process.  With your problem statement I expect that it takes so long to find the higher level primes that it does not matter.

As noted by the other answers, do not use the same stack for storing the prime values found by each thread (the amount of time required to work the lock will be excessive).  If you want the primes returned in a numeric order, I suggest either rewriting the loop which prints the primes so it goes through both stacks at the same time, printing the next value (by order).  Some thing like:

```
    while(!primes1.empty() && !primes2.empty())
    {
        if(primes1.top() > primes2.top())
        {
            printf("%d \t", primes1.top());
            primes1.pop();
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d \t", primes2.top());
            primes2.pop();
        }
    }
```

You would have to deal with the values left over in one stack once the other is empty (or maybe place a -1 at the bottom of each stack so if you either stack is empty then all values greater then -1 would already be printed).

The other solution would be to maintain a sorted list of primes which is updated every time a thread returns.  This could then be copied into the par struct for quicker prime detection (if a number is divisible evenly by an existing prime then the number is not prime).

Note: I have not tested these examples, though they should be close enough to give you the general idea.

Answer (score 3):

Terminating a thread violently is a bad idea since you it can leave your process in a bad state. If your thread is running in a loop you can set some flag externally that the thread can test and decide whether to terminate itself (this can be done by simply exiting the thead function). Just remember to protect your flag with a mutex.

There are some other patterns that you might want to look at. You might want to put your range of primes into a queue. Each worker thread can then pull values off the queue and perform the search. This way you can evenly split the load without killing and restarting threads.

Answer (score 0):

Your prime-finding algorithm is horribly inefficient but I want talk about that now..

Threading:

Set up a job queue for each thread.. killing/terminating short living threads, especially for prime finding sounds like a really bad idea.

Avoid contention. Don't use locking for `primes.push(i);`. set a separate queue for each thread, push the results there. When the thread finished with the range, *then* enter the criticalsection and merge the results. This way you hardly do locking.